# Scoping Rules in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am going through the book *JavaScript: The Complete Reference, Third Edition By: Thomas Powell; Fritz Schneider* to have a detailed understanding of the concepts.

> #### Scoping Rules
>
> Outside of a function or object, variables are within the global space whether  explicitly defined with var or not. Within a function or object, if the var statement is used, the defined variable will be local to the construct; without the statement, it will be global.
>
> Commonly, JavaScript developers make assumptions about scoping rules with var that aren’t quite true. For example, a var statement found within a for loop does not scope that value to the loop. In this case, it is scoped to either the function it is within or to the global space if it is outside a function or an object.

Just to see what happens consequently, I coded like this,

[image: Global & Local Variables]

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in Eclipse IDE for it to show JavaScript proposals, why am I able to access the variable jLocal outside the function?

As per the author description:

> *For example, a var statement found within a for loop does not scope that value to the loop. In this case, it is scoped to either the function it is within or to the global space if it is outside a function or an object.*

Comment: @apsillers : The program doesn't produce a output with jLocal = jLocal +j; So, why does Eclipse assumes jLocal - Global in screenshot attached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because at the bottom of your code you have:

```
...
jLocal = jLocal + j; // defined not in any functions
...
```

Making it global, but not necessary defined.

Comment: jLocal is defined in the second myFunc()

Comment: +1, when i comment those 2 lines at bottom, Eclipse does not propose.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari Yes but it's not the same `jLocal`, even though it has the same name. The one at the bottom is a completely different variable, a *global* `jLobal`. While the one in the function is a *local* one.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't the case of a local function. myFunc is global, just as the variable jLocal is (albeit the name). Because of hoisting, jLocal is assumed to be declared on top of parent scope.

Looking more carefully, there's two variable's named jLocal. One local to myFunc and an implicit one on global scope.

Want a tip?

Put `"use strict";` just before `var global1 = true;`. An HTML 5 implementation would be able to catch and show your error.